# SQL server alwayson 3 Node Primary Down

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, optimization, availability-groups, disaster-recovery

I am using three node alwayson Availability Group SQL 2012 Enterprise Edition.

2 Node in DC with File Share Witness quorum also in DC and third node to be setup in DR

I need to perform a DR switchover with all DC down And DR database up for applications.

Can this solution work or I need to use Log Shipping as third node instead of alwayson AG node.

Please help on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes , it should work considering 3rd node is part of same windows failover cluster.

I believe with 2 nodes you are trying to achieve HA and if 3rd node is in different data center it's ideal for DR.
.
Also I am not exactly sure when you say taking DC down, if both nodes down, then test the case for quorum as I guess you might be on windows 2012 and things are tricky there for odd/even majority of votes

Answer (score 0):

I guess you plan your DR node to be in "aSync mode".

If so, you should be able to trigger a manual failover (with possible data loss) in case of a DR (or a DR exercice).

The Quorum will be lost if you lose your DC (as 3 votes out of 4 (if you give a vote to your DR site) will be lost). This is not a problem if you have an async node that you manually failover. The Quorum is used for automatic failover (it allow the cluster to know where to failover).

As mentionned by KASQLDBA, this node needs to be in the same cluster as the other node.